# How to create a dynamic kivy app with checkboxes?

Tags: python, checkbox, dynamic, kivy

I'm doing a project for my university using kivy and python. I want to do a main screen where you can select some fields, and then the next screen will depend on the fields you have selected in the main screen. Doing dynamic with kv language is difficult to me because I don't know too much about programming with kivy, so i have decided to do like python programming but it doesn't work. Here you have the code of my program:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Builder.load_string('''
<Root>:
    MainScreen:
        name: 'main'
    AnotherScreen:
        name: 'another'

<MainScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            text: "Select Subjects"
            font_size: 15
        Label:
            text: " "
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('ch1')
        Label:
            text: "Termotecnia"
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('ch2')
        Label:
            text: "Control"
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('ch3')
        Label:
            text: "Termotcnia"
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('ch4')
        Label:
            text: "Control"
        Button:
            text: "Exit"
            background_color: .7, .7, 6, 1
            on_release:root.parent.current='another'
        Button:
            text: "Run"
            font_size: 24
            background_color: .7, .7, 1, 1
            on_release: root.parent.current='another'


''')


class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.a = App.get_running_app()
        self.e={}
    def ping(self,n):
        if self.a.big_dict[n]=='False':
            self.a.big_dict[n]='True'
        else: 
            self.a.big_dict[n]='False'
        print self.a.big_dict
        self.e=self.a.big_dict

class AnotherScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(AnotherScreen, self).__init__(**kw)
        t=[] 
        self.i=MainScreen()
        self.cols=2
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Assignatura',background_color=[0,1,1,1]))
        self.add_widget(Button(background_color=[0,1,1,1],text='Escriu Grup'))
        for k in self.i.e:
            if self.i.e[k]=='True':
                self.add_widget(Label(text=k))
                self.k=TextInput(multiline=False)
                t.append(self.k.text)
                self.add_widget(self.k)
            else:
                pass
        b1=Button(text='Exit',background_color=[0,1,0,1])
        self.add_widget(b1)
        b2=Button(text='Run',background_color=[0,1,0,1])
        self.add_widget(b2)
        b1.bind(on_press=exit)


class Root(ScreenManager):
    pass
class SimpleKivy(App):
    big_dict={'ch1':'False','ch2':'False','ch3':'False','ch4':'False'}
    def build(self):
        return Root()
SimpleKivy().run()
```

This code doesn't work because `ScreenManager` only works with a `Screen`, not with a `GridLayout` (first problem). The `big_dict` save the data of the checkboxes, but when I try to import to another class, it doesn't work (another problem). If anyone knows the answer to these problems it would be very helpful, because I know how to do with e.g. 13 fields always, but I want to do with a preselection, because there are too many fields (in this program only 4, but there are 14).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where to start...
First, let's look at `SimpleKivy`. You probably want to make `big_dict` a `DictProperty`, instead of a class attribute:

```
class SimpleKivy(App):
    big_dict = DictProperty({'ch1':False,'ch2':False,'ch3':False,'ch4':False})
```

I've also changed the values to booleans, because that will be more useful later.

Then, let's add another rule for `AnotherScreen` to the kv string:

```
<AnotherScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        id: container
        cols: 2
```

This way, we can refer to the actual layout by its `id`.

We also change the definition of `ping`:

```
def ping(self, n, value):
    self.a.big_dict[n] = value
```

When we then also change the `CheckBox`es in the `kv` string to

```
CheckBox:
    on_active:root.ping('ch1', self.active)
```

the state of the checkbox will be directly transferred to the dictionary in the app instance. (Alternatively, if you don't need `ping` for other things, this could be simplified to `on_active: app.big_dict['ch3'] = self.active`)

Finally, the definition of `AnotherScreen`:

```
class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        t=[] 
        a = App.get_running_app()
        self.ids.container.add_widget(Button(text='Assignatura',background_color=[0,1,1,1]))
        self.ids.container.add_widget(Button(background_color=[0,1,1,1],text='Escriu Grup'))
        for k,v in a.big_dict.iteritems():
            if v:
                self.ids.container.add_widget(Label(text=k))
                self.k=TextInput(multiline=False)
                t.append(self.k.text)
                self.ids.container.add_widget(self.k)
        b1=Button(text='Exit',background_color=[0,1,0,1])
        self.ids.container.add_widget(b1)
        b2=Button(text='Run',background_color=[0,1,0,1])
        self.ids.container.add_widget(b2)
        b1.bind(on_press=exit)
```

This is called before the screen is entered, will get the dictionary directly from the app instance (so no need to refer to `MainScreen`), and iterate over said dictionary.

Comment: So amazing! Do you know how to put the title of the main main Screen in the center of the Screen? (Select Subjects) I know is a silly question, but i don't know so much about kivy. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @A.Piquer you could make a vertical `BoxLayout` the child of `MainScreen`, and then add the `Label` and the `GridLayout` as its children

Comment: I'm trying to add more fields in the mainscreen but the program doesn't work. Do you know why happens this? I want to add 13 fields and when i add more to the dictionary and the checkboxes the kivy program doesn't run.

Comment: @A.Piquer no. You could ask a new question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022939/how-can-i-add-more-checkboxes-in-kivy-app-python-how-can-i-get-the-text-input Here is the new question. Thank you!