# How Can I add more CheckBoxes in Kivy App python?

Tags: android, python, checkbox, kivy

I'm doing a project about an app with Kivy and I have a few problems with it. The first problem is to add more checkboxes to the Main Screen. At the moment the mainscreen has 4 checkboxes with 1 label for check box and I need to have 13 checkboxes. When I try to add the same code the kivy app doesn't run, I don't know why, is very strange. The code of the program is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import DictProperty

Builder.load_string('''
<Root>:
    MainScreen:
        name: 'main'
    AnotherScreen:
        name: 'another'

<MainScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            text: "Select Subjects"
            font_size: 15
        Label:
            text: " "
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('240031',self.active)
        Label:
            text: "Electromagnetisme"
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('240033',self.active)
        Label:
            text: "Materials"
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('240052',self.active)
        Label:
            text: "Termodinàmica"
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('240053',self.active)
        Label:
            text: "Electrotècnia"
        Button:
            text: "Exit"
            background_color: .7, .7, 6, 1
            on_release:root.parent.current='another'
        Button:
            text: "Run"
            font_size: 24
            background_color: .7, .7, 1, 1
            on_release: root.parent.current='another'

<AnotherScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        id: container
        cols: 2

''')


class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.a = App.get_running_app()
        self.e={}
    def ping(self, n, value):
         self.a.big_dict[n] = value

class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        i={'240031':A,'240033':B,'240052':C,'240053':D}
        t=[]        
        a = App.get_running_app()
        self.ids.container.add_widget(Button(text='Assignatura',background_color=[0,1,1,1]))
        self.ids.container.add_widget(Button(background_color=[0,1,1,1],text='Escriu Grup'))
        for k,v in a.big_dict.iteritems():
            if v:
                self.ids.container.add_widget(Label(text=k+' '+i[k].encode("utf-8")))
                self.k=TextInput(multiline=False)
                t.append(self.k.text)
                self.ids.container.add_widget(self.k)
        def run(self):
            print t
        b1=Button(text='Exit',background_color=[0,1,0,1])
        self.ids.container.add_widget(b1)
        b2=Button(text='Run',background_color=[0,1,0,1])
        self.ids.container.add_widget(b2)
        b1.bind(on_press=exit)
        b2.bind(on_release=run)

class Root(ScreenManager):
     pass
class SimpleKivy(App):
    big_dict = DictProperty({'240031':False,'240033':False,'240052':False,'240053':False})
    def build(self):
        return Root()
SimpleKivy().run()
```

Here is the hole code. In the second screen the user can select some fields and save the textinput in the variable `t`, printing the results in the python screen. If someone knows how to add more check boxes in the Main Screen it would be very helpful.

Comment: It's best to focus on one problem per question, see [ask]. Also, if we don't have access to your code (such as the module `filtro`), it does not make sense to mention it. Better to structure the code so that we can run it as is.

Comment: Done. I'm working in filtro untill so I have decided to only print the results of the variables I need (`t`).

Comment: When you append `text` values to `t`, these are empty at time of creation. You need to [bind an event handler to the `text` property (see 3rd code snippet)](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#usage-example) to react to changes of the text. Or, if you want to act on the inputs when clicking `b2`, collect the `text`s in `run`.

Comment: And How I cant collect all the texts when run is clicked? I'm trying to save every text with `self.k.bind(on_text=add)` (`add` is a function that save into a list every change) but doesn't work, because bind adds every change e.g if I input '12', bind will save '1' and '12'. Do you know how to collect the final texts?

Comment: Store TextInputs in ListProperty at creation, then go through list and collect texts in run