# kivy variable from class to class

Tags: python, class, kivy

I want to transfer the variable `Overall` from `ScreenOne` to `ScreenTwo`. Is that possible?

```
class ScreenOne(Screen):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super (ScreenOne,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        x = random.randint(3,3)
        random_question = Questions[x][0]
        self.ans = Questions[x][5]
        self.Overall = 0


class ScreenTwo(Screen):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super (ScreenTwo,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        x = random.randint(0,99)
        random_question = Questions[x][0]
        self.ans = Questions[x][5]
        self.Overall = ScreenOne.Overall
```

Comment: `Overall` is an instance attribute. You need instances of `ScreenOne` and `ScreenTwo`. Your instance of `ScreenTwo` would have to know about the instance of `ScreenOne` – it could be passed in the constructor. Or both should have the same parameter determined by something else – then that parameter should be passed to both constructors. Hard to know without any context.

Comment: You can use an answer from this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35996077/5994041).